# Network Shared OneNote: Want it to be public viewing, but only private editing

Tags: permissions, document, public-website, shared-services

I have a shared OneNote document on a somewhat public SharePoint site. I want the document to keep its public viewing ability, but I don't want everyone to be able to go in and edit it. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set permissions on individual documents, just as you can on libraries. Just pull up the item menu and select Manage Permissions.